# How to create a firebaseArray with elements inside of a child with unique id?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, unique

I have a code structure where I ready the stores that works perfectly. However, I need to list promotions that are in each store and each promotion has a unique id so I would like to know how to list all the promotions that are inside every store follow the code:

in app.js

```
app.factory('Promos', function($firebaseArray){

    var ref = new Firebase('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/');
    var refPromoArray = $firebaseArray(ref);

    return{
    getPromos: function() {
        if (refPromoArray) {
            return $firebaseArray(ref.child('promotions'));
        }
    }
})
```

in controller.js

```
.controller('PromoListCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, $ionicLoading, Promos) {
    $scope.promoslist = Promos.getPromos();
    console.log($scope.promoslist);
})
```

in promo_list.html

```
<ion-list ng-if="promoslist.length > 0" can-swipe="true">
    <ion-item ng-repeat="promoslist in promo" type="item-text-wrap"
              href="#/app/local/{{promo.$id}}">
        <img ng-src="{{promo.photo}}" />
        {{local.title}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('/promotions/');
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
    console.log(data.key + " = " + data.val().yourpoerty);
});
```

Actually the snapshot is your array. If you want some sort of a normal array only with data, you can create one and add them manually in an array. Good luck.

Comment: Hello thank you for the answer your code worked to group the promotions, but now I have another problem, to list I changed the code to create an array with all the promotions as follows 2 Answers
:

Comment: It looks like the problem is how you add the data to the database, not how you read it. Check your Firebase Console for the structure and see if it is like you want it.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply, I created a database where I split the promotions in an open {promotions} -> [id store] -> [promotions] I can not change the bank anymore because my app is already in the store and The old versions will stop working, so I would just like to know how I can tailor the code into the foreach to create only one array of a dimension?.

Answer (score 0):

Hello thank you for the answer your code worked to group the promotions, but now I have another problem, to list I changed the code to create an array with all the promotions as follows:

**my code:**

```
var promoslist = [];

promos = ref.child('promotions');

            promos.on('value', function(snapshot) { 
                snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
                promoslist.push(data.val());
            });
            });



 **To list via the code below:**

   <ion-list ng-if="promoslist.length > 0">
  <Ion-item ng-repeat = "promo in promoslist">
      {{Promo}}
    </ Ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

In this case I have 2 stores with 4 promotions but the code is generating an array of two dimensions with the two promotions of each item so ng-repeat only runs twice showing only the results if I change the list to an index ex:

**Promoslist [0] or promoslist [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udGsP.jpg)**

```
<Ion-item ng-repeat = "promo in promoslist[0]">
```

I would like to just create an array of one dimension with all the promotions to list them all at once how do I create a simple array with all?

Follows the image of the result:

[Resuult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udGsP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution doing a loop-repeat combination in ng-repeat as following code:

```
<ion-list ng-if="promoslist.length > 0" can-swipe="true" >
<div ng-repeat="promo in promoslist[0]">
            <ion-item ng-repeat="promo in promoslist[$index]" type="item-text-wrap" class="item-avatar"
                      href="#/app/promo/{{promo.idstore}}/{{promo.id}}"  ng-if="promo.status==='active'">
                <img ng-src="{{promo.image}}"/>
                {{promo.title}}
                <p>{{promo.store}}</p>
            </ion-item>
            </div>
        </ion-list>
```